# How to eliminate repetitive lines in the file: python

Tags: python, string, file

We have 2 files: one with input data and one where we put the result. All the information in files goes in lines. The program should look for duplicate lines in the file and print only lines that don't repeat. Here is the example of the input data:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
banana
bargain
brick
brick
sample
sample
simple
text
text
text
```

Here is the example of the output file:

```
apple
banana
bargain
brick
sample
simple
text
```

Here is my code:

```
fileFrom = open ('data.txt', 'r')
fileTo = open ('result.txt', 'w')

line = fileFrom.readline()

while line != '':
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line == fileFrom.readline():
        line = fileFrom.readline()
    else:
        fileTo.write(line + '\n')
    line = fileFrom.readline()

fileFrom.close()
fileTo.close()
```

For some reason this program just reprints the input file.
My instructor told me not to use any structures as array or list so we have just to compare lines.

Comment: If you cant use a `list` (or `dict` or `set`?) then how are you supposed to store the lines you've already seen?

Comment: As I understand we can use only filename.readLine(), so we should somehow compare two adjacent lines. This is my idea.

Comment: The main question is how to compare adjacent lines because my "if" statement is always False, so the program always goes to "else"

Comment: Yep that's coz you've rstripped the first line but not rstripping the consecutive lines..

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj even after I deleted rstrip() line it didn't work.

Comment: And none of the answers didn't work either.

Comment: In the question your reading a line in the if condition as well as inside the if. That shouldn't be happening.Instead use a temporary variable. Also what did my answer return when you ran it?

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj the result for your answer is "apple".

Comment: @lili are you sure you are running the code correctly? My answer gives the expected output when I run it. I don't see how abisheks answer can produce just a single line. If the answers fail, comment on the individual answers. I can see some break your requirements by using sets or regex etc. Unless you call out those posters they'll assume their answers is OK even though they didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your reading lines too many times in your code for the 'if' comparison as well as inside the 'if'. Not just that you need to strip each line and only then compare as the initial line is stripped.

```
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as fileFrom:
    with open ('result.txt', 'w') as fileTo:
        line = fileFrom.readline()
        while line != '':
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            line2 = fileFrom.readline().rstrip('\n');
            while(line==line2):
                line2 = fileFrom.readline().rstrip('\n');
            fileTo.write(line +'\n')
            line = line2
```

Answer (score 2):

You compare two lines one of which you've stripped the newline and the other which you haven't, they will never match and all lines will be written.

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')            # stripped
    if line == fileFrom.readline(): # compare stripped to non-stripped
```

You are also doing too many readline operations. One initially the 3 in the loop this is reading the lines too often and looks to me like you might miss comparing some lines. It's much simpler to just iterate over the file using `for in` loop.

To fix compare the values when both have been `rstrip`ped. You do need to compare the stripped strings as the final line doesn't have a newline.

```
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as fileFrom:
    with open ('result.txt', 'w') as fileTo:
        last = ''
        for line in fileFrom:
            if line.rstrip() != last.rstrip():
                fileTo.write(line)
                last = line
```

This solution given the constraints of the question, only picks out duplicate lines if all the duplicates are grouped together on subsequent lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
if line == fileFrom.readline():
        line = fileFrom.readline()
```

You are calling "fileFrom.readline()" method two times per each line. That's why your code doesn't work properly.

You can use this code.

```
fileFrom = open("data.txt", "r")
fileTo = open("result.txt", "w")
unique_lines = set()
for line in fileFrom.readlines():
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line not in unique_lines: # check the duplicate lines
        fileTo.write(line+'\n')
        unique_lines.add(line)
fileTo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First iterate each line , strip unwanted character and add it to set, So the only unique value would be there, Once you have set of unique value you can write it to file.

You can use following code

```
fileFrom = open ('data.txt', 'r')
fileTo = open ('result.txt', 'w')


def readFile():
    lines=set()
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.add(line.strip())
        return lines

def writeToFile(lines):
    for line in lines:
        fileTo.write(line + '\n')

lines=readFile()
print lines
if lines:
    writeToFile(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use regex? if you can you may try this for print each item one time:

```
import re 
file1 = open("inputrep","r").read()
file2 = open("output.txt","w")
file2.write(re.sub(r"(\w+\n)\1+",r"\1",file1))
file2.close()
```